Replacing primitive with signal fails to load the value correctly
I have a component that displays several tabs and uses a variable to determine which tab is open, the value of which is stored in a service as it is necessary to reload the last open tab when the user returns to the screen.
I decided to replace the implementation of this with angulars signals but it fails to reload the stored variable value correctly, forcing me to wrap the initialization in a timeout:
// tab.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
  activeId = signal('role-policy')
}

// the component
activeId: string = 'role-policy';

constructor(public tabService: TabService) {
    // Load our stored tab
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.activeId = this.tabService.activeId();
    }, 100);
}

The class variable is updated when the tab is changed:
<uxa-tab-group variant="primary" size="medium" [(activeId)]="activeId">

The value of the service is updated when the component is destroyed:
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tabServie.activeId.set(this.activeId);
}

If I remove the timeout and just have the assignment the value isn't set correctly:
constructor(public tabService: TabService) {
    // Load our stored tab
    this.activeTab = this.tabService.activeTab();

    // this.activeTab is still 'role-policy' 
    // this.tabService.activeTab() has the correct value
}

I thought the signal value wasn't being updated correctly but if I print it after or before the assignment it has the correct value.
I know this has to do with Angular's change detection but I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

I suspect you are expecting a signal input in the uxa-tab-group component.  Then you probably shouldn't assign the value of the signal but the signal itself: try to change: this.activeTab = this.tabService.activeTab() to this.activeTab = this.tabService.activeTab.

@user3791775 by removing the brackets an error will be introduced as the class variable is a string the service uses a signal; the exact error is: Type 'WritableSignal' is not assignable to type 'string'

I think activeTab should be Signal and you should expect a signal input (see the documentation: https://angular.dev/guide/signals/inputs). When doing that, change detection will probably work.

To simplify the code, you can use a signal, this enables us to do two way binding directly to the service, hence letting you save lines of code.
model signal would be preferred, but since you are using the signal on a service, we can only use a signal since model "can only be used on a component or directive"
On the service change it to a model.
// tab.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
  activeId = signal('role-policy'); // <- changed here!
}

On the component, create a getter/setter to access the model or just assign it to a property of model type. Here I am doing the latter method.
<uxa-tab-group variant="primary" size="medium" 
[(activeId)]="tabService.activeId">


You're referring to ModelSignal right? Unfortunately that was introduced in angular 17.2, my version is 17.0.1. I won't beable to upgrade the version for a while so I can't use this method.

@Katana24 try now, I updated with regular signal

@Katana24 But the concept remains the same, directly access the signal without the need for an extra variable.
